# Dell G5 5590 - Is possible to convert RTX 2060 mobile to RTX 2070?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, vram

Since both RTX2060 and RTX 2070 models of Dell G5 5590 uses the same TU-106 chip and the motherboard (vulcan15_n18e Rev A00) have two "free" VRAM slots in the RTX 2060 version and the VRMs seen to be the same in both versions (please, see the pictures below), it is possible to convert a RTX 2060 model into a RTX 2070 one?

What I'm intend to do is solder two new 1 GB VRAM chips and the capacitors around it and flash a RTX 2070 bios in the bios chip (with a bios reprogrammer). I'm probably missing the need to replace a resistor used in the chip initialization test (as in the conversion from RTX 2070 Super to a RTX 2080), but I couldn't find that information, neither the motherboards schemes.

Dell G5 5590 - RTX 2060 model close up:
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H7fb8900697fe45b9b77a1d3d1c59c855N.jpg

Dell G5 5590 - RTX 2070 model close up:
https://ae04.alicdn.com/kf/H672f2e3842564e119666c43aec3149b2f.jpg

BIOS - RTX 2070 - Max-Q Design:
https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/212990/212990

Comment: What you describe is a great way to brick your GPU during a world wide shortage of GPUs

Comment: The fact that you used the word "weld" makes me think that you probably shouldn't be doing what you are talking about.  This isn't a trailer hitch.

Comment: About the "weld", in fact, I didn’t know what the most suitable term for circuits... "Solder" should be better. I have experience with BGA soldering, but not as much with English